# MYSQL post query - not working need advise

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, post

Can someone take a look at this and maybe see why this is not updating my database?

It is a form that pulls data from my database and when I click the update button it SHOULD update the database, but it dosn't.

Is there a way to show if it is returning a error?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Beerlist Admin</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php include '../beerlist/config.php'; ?>
<table border="0" width="95%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>

<?php

#///////////////////////////////////
#//////////// ALL BEERS/////////////
#///////////////////////////////////
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bottles ORDER BY name";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql,$con);

if (isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE bottles SET new='$_POST[new]', name='$_POST[name], style='$_POST[style], location='$_POST[location], size='$_POST[size], abv='$_POST[abv], number='$_POST[number], price='$_POST[price]' WHERE name='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query ($UpdateQuery, $con);

};


while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){

echo "<form action=beerlist_admin.php method=post>";

    echo "<td><input size=7 type=text name=new value=\"" . $record['new'] . "\" > ";
    echo "<input type=text size=50 name=name value=\"" . $record['name'] . "\" >";
    echo "<input type=text size=20 name=style  value=\"" . $record['style'] . "\" >";
    echo "<input type=text size=20 name=location  value=\"" . $record['location'] . "\" >";
    echo "<input type=text size=7 name=size   value=\"" . $record['size'] . "\" >";
    echo "<input type=text size=5 name=abv   value=\"" . $record['abv'] . "\" >";
    echo "<input type=text size=5 name=number   value=\"" . $record['number'] . "\" >";
    echo "<input type=text size=7 name=price   value=\"" .$record['price'] . " \" >";
    echo "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['number'] . "\"> <input type=submit name=update value=update></td></tr>";

echo "</form>";
}

echo "</table>"
?>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can check `mysql_error` for error messages.  Given that this code is ***wide open*** to SQL injection attacks, anything could be happening to your database.  I highly recommend some light reading on the subject: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Start by properly handling errors with your mysql_*. [See here for examples of connect error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and [here for example of query error handling.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) You're also missing a single quote `'` for almost all your records on the UPDATE query, which will cause error for composite words.

Comment: You should put variables in braces inside your query, like `{$_POST['....']}`.

Comment: can you make sure that the control is going to the if (isset($_POST['update'])){ part of your code ?

Comment: milion error you have , and messing codes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First and foremost, `mysql_*` has been deprecated and you should consider migrating to MySQLi or PDO and be prepared for when `mysql_*` gets removed so your site does not stop working.**

---

Your code is wide open to SQL Injection you should use [**`mysql_real_escape_string($variable)`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent that.

With a combination of [**`sprintf`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) you can further define what kind of variable you are expecting, for example:

`%s` - is meant to be used for string data.
`%d` - is meant to be used for numbers, and presented as a (signed) decimal number.

On your the below example I've used only %s as I am unsure of the data you're trying to insert and your database table field types.

Your `UPDATE` query is poorly written and may cause issues in different cases depending on the data you provide it with so you should always be using the [**`mysql_error`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) at least during the development process so you can debug this sort of errors and once you move to a live site make those errors get logged silently to file instead.

You don't need to always use `echo` to print every little piece of HTML, see how I've changed your `WHILE` code.

Also the way you're using the form within the table while it may work its not the correct way.

Since you have not posted the contents of `config.php` I can't tell if there is any issues in there as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Beerlist Admin</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('beerlist', $con);
if (!$db_selected)
{
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
<table border="0" width="95%" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $UpdateQuery = sprintf("UPDATE bottles 
                               SET new='%s', 
                                   name='%s', 
                                   style='%s',
                                   location='%s',
                                   size='%s',
                                   abv='%s',
                                   number='%s',
                                   price='%s'
                             WHERE name='%s'",
                             mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['new']),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['style']),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['size']),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abv']),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number']),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hidden']));
    if (!mysql_query($UpdateQuery))
    {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM bottles 
      ORDER BY name";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$mydata)
{
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata))
{
?>
<form action="beerlist_admin.php" method="post">
<tr><td>
<input size="7" type="text" name="new" value="<?php echo $record['new']; ?>">
<input type="text" size="50" name="name" value="<?php echo $record['name']; ?>">
<input type="text" size="20" name="style" value="<?php echo $record['style']; ?>">
<input type="text" size="20" name="location" value="<?php echo $record['location']; ?>">
<input type="text" size="7" name="size" value="<?php echo $record['size']; ?>">
<input type="text" size="5" name="abv" value="<?php echo $record['abv']; ?>">
<input type="text" size="5" name="number" value="<?php echo $record['number']; ?>">
<input type="text" size="7" name="price" value="<?php echo $record['price']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $record['number']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
</td></tr>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help and constructive criticism.  I am brand new to this and learning from youtube videos. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zr0ktM3fjaI

Comment: @CoopersSeafood that video is pretty old, you should look for some newer tutorial that uses PDO instead, not only PDO is better in many ways but will save you a lot of trouble with the prepared statements. [Here is one: Introduction to PHP PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)

Comment: Prix,  Thanks again for helping me out.  I tried you code and I still can not get it to actually update the database.  my config file looks like this: <?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con){
    die("Can not connect:" . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("beerlist",$con);
?>

Comment: @CoopersSeafood and do you get any errors? Have you check the error_log file? also I have updated my ode with your config file give it a try.